# Is it possible to write out Oauth Token from Azure Powershell for debugging

Tags: azure-powershell

After authentication with `Add-AzureRMAccount` i would like to print out the oauth token to debug its claims.

Is this possible in Azure Powershell?

Comment: Does my answer address your question?

Comment: Ye. leaving it open for a day or two. Maybe someone else have some information.

Comment: Sure, completely agree.

Comment: Hi, it seems there is no more input other than my update. Is this acceptable for answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The output object from **`Add-AzureRMAccount`** only has the following properties:

- Environment
- Account
- TenantId
- SubscriptionId
- CurrentStorageAccount

Even with the **`-Debug`** switch for **`Add-AzureRMAccount`**, the debug messages also do not print out the actual OAuth token, only the token hash is printed out.

[image]

Update 1: Tested again with the **Microsoft Azure PowerShell January 2016 (1.1.0)**

Still only show the token hash.

[image]